# If set A is equivalent to a subset of N then is A countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

There’s not really much context to this. Is this connected to the fact that if A is equivalent to the set of natural number then A is countable(more specifically countably infinite)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is connected to the countability of the naturals. We can more precisely claim a set $S$ is countable if there exists an injection $S \to \Bbb N$ (or to any other countable set, e.g. $\Bbb Z, \Bbb Q$). For clarity, we say $S$ is countable if $|S| \le \aleph_0$.

More generally, if there exists an injection $A \to B$, then we have that $|A| \le |B|$. (Similarly a surjection would have $|A| \ge |B|$, assuming the Axiom of Choice, and a bijection would have $|A|=|B|$.)

Comment: In general (without assuming Axiom of Choice), the existence of a surjection one way does not imply the existence of an injection the other way (assuming this existence is actually equivalent to AoC). Injection implies surjection, though. Comparing cardinalities is customarily defined in terms of injections.

Comment: @Arthur So basically I should reframe my post in terms of injections in lieu of surjections? Just want to be sure I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: For injections into / surjections out of $\Bbb N$ (and maybe the other way too?), those are equivalent. It is mostly that last paragraph about generalities which I think you should rephrase.

Comment: Eh I'll go ahead and rephrase both since it'd be weird to switch without prompting.

Answer (score 0):

Following the lead of @EeveeTrainer, we can use following definition:

**Countable set**: Let $A$ be a set. $A$ is countable iff there exists an injection $c:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $A\cong B$. Recall that this means there exists an injection $i:A \hookrightarrow B$ (which is also a bijection). Now, if there exists an injection $c:B \hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ i.e. if $B$ is countable, we can compose maps $c$ and $i$ to get an injection $c \circ i:A \hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}$, thereby proving that $A$ is also countable. (Notice I used the fact that composition of two injections results in an injection).

As an aside, note that this does not require B to be a subset of natural numbers in the membership-based set theory sense.